# A question about opposite ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reading this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_ring) about opposite rings. Are there relevant (or important) results about those rings? What opposite rings for?

Comment: The opposite ring (or rather 'algebra') is the inverse element in the [Brauer group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group).

Comment: Every ring is the opposite of some other ring... They don't form a special class of rings. Any general result about "opposite rings" is a result about all rings. As for their utility, I think it is merely formal, for instance, if one doesn't want to talk about left *and* right modules, opposite rings come into play. Although there are important constructions involving the opposite of a ring, for instance, given a ring $R$, the ring structure on $R\otimes R^{\mathrm{op}}$ has some utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe seeing it used in a few places will help give an idea of why the notation is useful.

For the right module $R_R$, the ring of $R$ module endomorphisms is $End(R_R)\cong R$. However, the ring of endomorphisms for the left $R$ module $_RR$ is $End(_RR)\cong R^{op}$.

Another link is this: for any left $R$ module $M$, there's a ring homomorphism from $R$ into $End(M_\Bbb Z)$ (the additive group homomorphisms.) But for a right $R$ module, it's a homomorphism from $R^{op}\to End(M_\Bbb Z)$.

More generally, an $R,S$ bimodule $M$ is equivalent to a ring homomorphism from $R\otimes_\Bbb Z S^{op}\to End(M_\Bbb Z)$.